# Python Flask HTML Routing arguments

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm designing a website for my college technical fest which is in 3 days. I've got most of the code working but I'm still not able to get the static webpage with the youtube URL to load. It gives a positional error argument

Attaching the code for the python flask app route and html code for the static webpage

```
#Python Flask Code
@app.route('/')
def video():
    return video('video.html')
```

```
#HTML Static Page code
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Blog entries{% endblock %} {% block content_title %}{% if search %}Search "{{
    search }}"{% else %}Blog entries{% endif %}{% endblock %} {% block content %}

<div class="blog py-4">
    <h3 class="section-title tex-center m-5">Event Videos</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="py-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <iframe width="892" height="502" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t9FT9MKvO4c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>            
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain what the error is here?

Below is the error that is showing in CMD on Windows

```
[2020-02-22 20:22:06,385] ERROR in app: Exception on /video/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\rosch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "colo.py", line 355, in video
    return video('video.html')
TypeError: video() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2020 20:22:06] "[35m[1mGET /video/ HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
```

Comment: What do you expect `video('video.html')` to do?

Comment: I got the error to go away but now the page is not getting rendered

Comment: @KlausD. I have to get the page that contains the videos to load. That page is static and needs to have the youtube videos uploaded as iframes

Comment: What's the directory structure of your application?

Answer (score 1):

`video` is the name of the function bound to the route `/`. As the error message implies, you are attempting to call that very function by passing to it the name of the template you wish to render. However, `video`'s signature contains no parameters. Instead, simply use `flask.render_template`:

```
@app.route('/')
def video():
  return flask.render_template('video.html')
```

Comment: It actually caused the error to go away but now the page just won't show

Comment: @RoschRocks Are you storing `video.html` in a `templates` folder?